# Не корректно работает код

Tags: javascript

Проблема заключается в том что либо добавляются все ключи в массив reasons либо ни один. А должны добавляться те которые прошли проверку

```js
const filters = {
    age: function (element) {
        return element >= 25;
    },
    education: function (element) {
        return element === 'higher'
    },
    experience: function (element) {
        return element >= 1
    }
}
const employee = {};
const defaultDescriptors = {
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
}
Object.defineProperties(employee, {
    name: {
        ...defaultDescriptors,
        value: 'Dmitriy',
        writable: false
    },
    age: {
        ...defaultDescriptors,
        value: 21
    },
    education: {
        ...defaultDescriptors,
        value: 'higher'
    },
    experience: {
        ...defaultDescriptors,
        value: 0
    }
})
function hireNewEmployee (employee,filters) {
    const reasons = [];
    Object.entries(filters).forEach(([name]) => {
        if (filters.experience(employee.experience) === false) {
            reasons.push(name);
        } else if (filters.education(employee.education) === false) {
            reasons.push(name);
        } else if (filters.experience(employee.experience) === false) {
            reasons.push(name);
        }
    })
    if (reasons.length > 0) {
    return `Not hired: sorry we cannot hire you. Here is why: ${reasons.join(', ')}`
}
else {
    return 'You are Hired! Congrats!'
}
}
console.log(hireNewEmployee(employee,filters))
```

Comment: Зачем вы пишите `return console.log()`?

Comment: @EzioMercer я изменил вывод в консоль. Но проблему мне не удалось решить.

Comment: У вас какое условие принятия на работу? Если хотябы один пункт не подошёл, то не берёте или если хотябы один пункт подошёл, то берёте? Или там есть приоритеты?

Comment: @EzioMercer age>=25; experience>=1; education===higher. Если все условия выполняются то в консоль выводится You are Hired! Congrats! Если одно из условий или все не выполняются то в консоль выводится Not hired: sorry we cannot hire you. Here is why: ${reasons.join(', '), где reasons это массив с условиями которые не подошли

Comment: Ну так `experience` у вас `0`, вы проверяете `>= 1` вам возвращается `false` и всё, уже после первого `if`-а у вас в массиве есть причина. Вам надо грамотно условия переписать

Comment: @EzioMercer не очень вас понимаю как мне условие изменить

Comment: Я вам описал проблему, вернее то как работает ваша программа. Как менять зависит от ваших задумок :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вот так:

```
function hireNewEmployee (employee,filters) {
    const reasons = [];
    Object.entries(filters).forEach(([name,func]) => {
        if (func(employee[name]) === false) {
            reasons.push(name);
        }
    })
    if (reasons.length > 0) {
        return `Not hired: sorry we cannot hire you. Here is why: ${reasons.join(', ')}`
    }
    else {
        return 'You are Hired! Congrats!'
    }
}
console.log(hireNewEmployee(employee,filters));
```